# Using multiple while loops?

Tags: python, csv

I've got a code that was working really well.  I was able to make it print a single line with the 2008 rows.  However, when I decided to loop it in order to increment it to 2014, it gets stuck.  Is there a better way to do this?  I really thought I had it for a minute there.  The csv file has multiple "titles" in the center column, and the left column is years from 2008 up to 2014.  The values are in the right column and vary for every row.

Here's the code I have:

```
import csv
from math import floor
import sys

ohu = 'Occupied Housing Units'
vhu = 'Vacant Housing Units'
thu = 'Total Housing Units'
yr = 2008
limit = 2014
filename = 'denton_housing.csv'


with open(filename, 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f:
    housing_stats = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=','):
        year = int(row['year'])
        field_name = row['title_field']
        value = int(row['value'])
        denton_dict = {'year': year, 'title_field': field_name, 'value': value}
        housing_stats.append(denton_dict)

        while int(row['year']) >= yr and int(row['year']) <= limit and row['title_field'] == vhu:
            vac_unit = int(row['value'])
        while int(row['year']) >= yr and int(row['year']) <= limit and row['title_field'] == thu:
            tot_unit = int(row['value'])
        while int(row['year']) >= yr and int(row['year']) <= limit and row['title_field'] == ohu:
            occ_unit = int(row['value'])
            print(yr, "             ", "{0:.0f}%".format(100 * (vac_unit / tot_unit)),\
        "                      ", "{0:.0f}%".format((occ_unit / tot_unit) * 100))
            yr+1
```

Comment: well as far as I know there isn't better way

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything that breaks you out of the while loop. It looks like e.g. `vac_unit` just keeps getting set to the same value over and over again, and it won't stop because the value of `vac_unit` is not checked in your `while` statement.

What are you trying to achieve within each of the while loops? Are you trying to iterate over the rows?

Comment: I was hoping that the `(row['year'])` was incremented by the `yr+1`, the `int(row['value'])` would change to the value the new year represents in the csv.

Comment: Will you be able to provide more details on what error you are getting? Also, I don't see how `(row['year'])` is being incremented by `yr+1`.

Comment: It's not being incremented, I now realize.  Only the `== yr` is being incremented.  I realize that doing what I thought I could do isn't possible and is way beyond my abilities.  I'm in a class that is too far beyond what anyone in the class can do, and it's been frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 `while` loops, only the last includes your incrementor, and your incrementor should be `yr += 1` (which is short for `yr = yr = 1`) not just `yr+1`.

You will also need to change your approach, because you are wanting to iterate over the years as well as over the rows.

I would suggest keeping a dictionary of years, and the vhu, ohu and thu data for each year. The end result might look like `{'2008': {'vhu': 1, 'ohu': 5, 'thu': 6}, '2009': ...}.